# OCaml function using List module

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to implement the following:

```
let list = [1;2;3;4];;

if ((List.exists 3 list) = true)
 print_string "element exists in list\n"
```

But it is giving me the error: This expression has type int list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a -> bool

I am not sure what this means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.exists` takes a *function* and a list, not a value and a list. For testing whether a value is in a list, use `List.mem`.

Your `if` looks like C syntax. In OCaml you need to use `then` (but you don't need the parentheses).

As a side comment, `if e = true then ...` is the same as `if e then ...`. If you use good names for things, the latter is usually clearer.